# Can we say "admitted to the mistakes"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, subject-verb-inversion

Can we say "***admitted to*** the mistakes"?   I think it should be *admitted the mistakes* and *admitted **to** the hospital*.

The sentence that I am working on is

> it has not admitted to the mistakes in the monetary policy, nor it has sought to explain

Also I have some doubts regarding the usage of "has" after *nor*— the correct answer given says "has it"

Could someone explain the reasons for these usages.

Answer (score 1):

Read it, **along with** the part omitted by ellipsis if need be,

"admitted to (**having committed** ) the mistakes".

This is legalese/ bureaucratese anyway, so it works; and no one's complaining either. There's no issue about its grammar or its readability, esp., given the context.

Answer (score 0):

> "It has not admitted to* **its** mistakes **regarding** monetary policy, nor **has it** sought to explain **them**."

*The *to* here is optional. (Running Google searches on variations of "he/she/they admitted [to] his/her/their mistakes" suggests that the form without *to* occurs about twice as often as the form that includes it.)

Answer (score -4):

Why 'it'? Ordinarily human agents make admissions and give explanations.

More context would be helpful.

'Admitted to making mistakes' is how I would express it.

Comment: My guess is that it is an agency (The Fed, for example) that is facing questions about mistakes it may have made.  So *it* could be appropriate, and *the* might be used because the sentence is discussing some particular mistakes the agency is being accused of making. (Not my -1)

Comment: Please make sure your response answers the question. It isn't a place for questions or comments.

Comment: The first two sentences are not relevant to the question (which is about ***admit to***) and the last is unsubstantiated opinion. This isn't a discussion forum: answers are expected to be rigorous.